# Storing a value as a variable in Postman when multiple values have same name

Tags: json, postman

I am currently working on a project involving storing an upcoming bus arrival time in a variable using a test script. When I run the API request I am given this result:

```json
{
    "route_departures": [
        {
            "global_route_id": "TSL:1900",
            "itineraries": [
                {
                    "branch_code": "",
                    "direction_headsign": "*******",
                    "direction_id": 0,
                    "headsign": "*******"",
                    "merged_headsign": "*******"",
                    "schedule_items": [
                        {
                            "departure_time": 1709116320,
                            "is_cancelled": false,
                            "is_real_time": false,
                            "rt_trip_id": "13714672",
                            "scheduled_departure_time": 1709116320,
                            "trip_search_key": "TSL:44646441:935:4:0",
                            "wheelchair_accessible": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "departure_time": 1709116980,
                            "is_cancelled": false,
                            "is_real_time": false,
                            "rt_trip_id": "13714671",
                            "scheduled_departure_time": 1709116980,
                            "trip_search_key": "TSL:44646441:934:4:0",
                            "wheelchair_accessible": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "departure_time": 1709118780,
                            "is_cancelled": false,
                            "is_real_time": false,
                            "rt_trip_id": "13714665",
                            "scheduled_departure_time": 1709118780,
                            "trip_search_key": "TSL:44646441:934:4:1",
                            "wheelchair_accessible": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "mode_name": "Bus",
            "real_time_route_id": "6841",
            "route_color": "1e4f75",
            "route_long_name": "*******"",
            "route_network_id": "*******"",
            "route_network_name": "*******"",
            "route_short_name": "N9",
            "route_text_color": "ffffff",
            "route_type": 3,
            "sorting_key": "N9",
            "tts_long_name": "*******"",
            "tts_short_name": "N9"
        },
        {
            "global_route_id": "TSL:1894",
            "itineraries": [
                {
                    "branch_code": "",
                    "direction_headsign": "*******"",
                    "direction_id": 0,
                    "headsign": "*******"",
                    "merged_headsign": "*******"",
                    "schedule_items": [
                        {
                            "departure_time": 1709056473,
                            "is_cancelled": false,
                            "is_real_time": true,
                            "rt_trip_id": "13681045",
                            "scheduled_departure_time": 1709056080,
                            "trip_search_key": "TSL:44646441:317:3:17",
                            "wheelchair_accessible": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "departure_time": 1709057220,
                            "is_cancelled": false,
                            "is_real_time": true,
                            "rt_trip_id": "13681044",
                            "scheduled_departure_time": 1709057040,
                            "trip_search_key": "TSL:44646441:317:3:18",
                            "wheelchair_accessible": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "departure_time": 1709058031,
                            "is_cancelled": false,
                            "is_real_time": true,
                            "rt_trip_id": "13681043",
                            "scheduled_departure_time": 1709057940,
                            "trip_search_key": "TSL:44646441:317:3:19",
                            "wheelchair_accessible": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "mode_name": "Bus",
            "real_time_route_id": "6667",
            "route_color": "2a61a0",
            "route_long_name": "*******",
            "route_network_id": "T*******"",
            "route_network_name": "*******"",
            "route_short_name": "160",
            "route_text_color": "ffffff",
            "route_type": 3,
            "sorting_key": "160",
            "tts_long_name": "*******"",
            "tts_short_name": "1 60"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to store the value of `departure_time` for the soonest upcoming departure of the "TSL 1900" route in a variable using a test script.

I am a beginner to postman and working with APIs in general and have very limited knowledge of JSON so chances are my solutions are not something that would ever work in this situation.

Please note I have censored any geographic information for my personal privacy.

I have used this test script and it did not give the desired result at all.

```
console.log(pm.response.json())
const route_departures = pm.response.json().route_departures
const itineraries = route_departures.itineraries
const schedule_items = itineraries.schedule_items
let upcoming_departure = schedule_items.departure_time
```

This is the result that it yielded.

[image: This is the result that comes from this test script]

I have also attempted to use this test script:

```
console.log(pm.response.json())
const route_departures = pm.response.json().route_departures
const itineraries = route_departures.itineraries
pm.environment.set("upcoming_arrival", itineraries.schedule_items[0].departure_time);
```

and received this error:

[image: this is the error that I received]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 2):

You needs to understand JSON syntax first

##### JSON background

#1
An object in JSON is enclosed within curly braces {}. It consists of key-value pairs, where keys must be strings enclosed in double quotes "",

"key": value (no quotes for number or boolean, strings enclosed in double quotes "")

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 21,
  "city": "New York"
}
```

#2 `Array`
An array in JSON is enclosed within square brackets [].

```
[
  "apple",
  "banana",
  "orange"
]
```

To access the first element "apple", you would use the index [0], like so:

`array[0]` -> "apple"

`array[1]` -> "banana"

`array[2]` -> "orange"

So
Starting with {}: This indicates that the JSON represents an object. The content inside the curly braces will consist of key-value pairs.

Starting with []: This indicates that the JSON represents an array. The content inside the square brackets will consist of values, which can be of any JSON data type.

##### Postman background

#1 jsonData
jsonData refers to the JSON data returned from the API response.

```
const jsonData = pm.response.json();
```

#2 console.log(): console.log() is a JavaScript function used to log messages to the console.

#3 Array Access

```
jsonData.route_departures[0]
```

jsonData.route_departures[0] refers to accessing the first element (index 0) of the route_departures array within the jsonData object.

[image]

[image]

Easy debug to print the value by `console.log()`

Console (lower and left side in Postman)

[image]

##### Find soonest depart time for TSL:1900

`Tests` tab

```
const jsonData = pm.response.json();

// Find the entry for the "TSL 1900" route
var tsl1900Route = jsonData.route_departures.find(route => route.global_route_id === "TSL:1900");

// If the route is found, find the soonest departure time
if (tsl1900Route) {
    const soonestDepartureTimeUnix = Math.min(...tsl1900Route.itineraries[0].schedule_items.map(item => item.departure_time));
    const soonestDepartureTime = new Date(soonestDepartureTimeUnix * 1000).toLocaleString();
    console.log("Soonest Departure Time:", soonestDepartureTimeUnix);
    console.log("Soonest Departure Time (Readable):", soonestDepartureTime);
} else {
    console.log("TSL 1900 route not found");
```

Result on Console

```
Soonest Departure Time:
1709116320
 
Soonest Departure Time (Readable):
2/28/2024, 5:32:00 AM
```

[image]